# Spring @Cacheable with filter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, ehcache, spring-cache

Every entity class has user.id value, I have filters on all services which filters data by principal.id and entity user.id on database level, simply adds where clause. I started to using @Cacheable spring option. But filters not works with spring-cache. How can I filter data from cache ?

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "countries")
public List<Country> getAll() {
    return countryDao.findAll();
}
```

Different user has access to values other users if values are in cache.

Answer (score 5):

From documentation
"As the name implies, @Cacheable is used to demarcate methods that are cacheable - that is, methods for whom the result is stored into the cache so on subsequent invocations (with the same arguments), the value in the cache is returned without having to actually execute the method."

In your case you don't have arguments therefore every time getAll is invoked it will return the cached version.

If your countryDao.findAll() inject the userid at database level, you have an issue as the first user calling countryDao.findAll() will cause his result to be cached, therefore other users will get the same result of the first user.

In general, if I understood how you designed the service, it is common that you don't inject the user at db level but pass it at service level so that this is decoupled from the current session (for example a web request).

However if you want to keep like that, it could still work by doing:

```
@Cacheable(value = "countries", key="#user.id")
public List<Country> getAll(User user) {     
    return countryDao.findAll();
}
```

All you have to do is pass the user to the method even if you don't use it explicitly (but the caching will).

Comment: I solved this problem with custom implementation of key generator with additional param - logged user id, but finally I used ehcache as hibernate second level cache due to problem with lazy loading problem with cached data. Thanks anyway :)